# PHP $_REQUEST doesn't contain all $_GET variables

Tags: php

Until today I thought that $_REQUEST always contains all variables form $_POST and $_GET.

But today I had the strange experience that one variable is part of $_GET but not part of $_REQUEST. I played a little bit around with the URL which hands over the parameters and it seems like always the fist parameter is missing in the $_REQUEST array.

Do you have any idea why this could happen?

Thanks!

**URL:**

```
localhost/?app=files&getfile=ajax/newfile.php?dir=%2Ftest4&source=http%3A%2F%2Fl‌​ocalhost%2Fimg%2Flogo.svg&filename=logo.svg&requesttoken=e250827c341650990cd4
```

Comment: Could you share some code with us, so we're able to see what you're doing?

Comment: could you provide us with some data; the uri you are using, the output of `print_r($_GET)` and the output of `print_r($_REQUEST)`?

Comment: In particular the query string you're sending.

Comment: Because some code is mucking around with the contents of `$_REQUEST` or (more likely) `$_GET`.

Comment: How much arguments do You have in Your GET? Per browser there is limitation for only e.g. 40 GET parameters (FF), 30 (IE7), etc... Nonetheless, I would recommend not to use $_REQUEST but always use only $_GET or $_POST where needed and **not** to rely on the $_REQUEST as it could be a potential exploit entry gate...

Comment: The URL looks like this and I can't get the dir parameter with $_REQUEST if I add a dummy parameter in front everything works fine: localhost/?app=files&getfile=ajax/newfile.php?dir=%2Ftest4&source=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fimg%2Flogo.svg&filename=logo.svg&requesttoken=e250827c341650990cd4

Comment: Click "edit" to modify the content of your question, it will be easier to read.

Answer (score 5):

Your `getfile` variable isn't properly encoded:

```
localhost/?app=files&getfile=ajax/newfile.php?dir=%2Ftest4&source=http%3A%2F%2Fl‌​ocalhost%2Fimg%2Flogo.svg&filename=logo.svg&requesttoken=e250827c341650990cd4
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The first variable in a URL GET request comes after a question mark (`?`). All additional variables must follow an ampersand (`&`).

If you have multiple question marks in your URL, then you are breaking protocol and you will probably cause confusion. I would bet that your second variable is missing the text: `ajax/newfile.php`.

Your URL should look like this:

```
localhost/?app=files&getfile=app%3Dfiles%26getfile%3Dajax%2Fnewfile.php%3Fdir%3D%252Ftest4&source=http%3A%2F%2Fl‌​ocalhost%2Fimg%
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You can encode URL variables in PHP using the `urlencode()` function.

Answer (score 0):

`dir` is a query parameter for the *uri* in the `getfile` parameter. As such, it will not be inside `$_GET` (and therefore `$_REQUEST`).

You will need to parse `$_GET['getfile']` with something like [`parse_url()`](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.parse-url.php) or restructure your query string.